# python smtp TypeError: sendmail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'

Tags: python, tkinter, smtp

```
import tkinter
import smtplib
import socket

from email.parser import Parser

smtp = smtplib.SMTP

user = ""
password = ""

def connect():
    print(msg_entry.get())

    smtp("localhost",25)
    #smtp.login(user,password)
    smtp.sendmail(from_entry.get(),to_entry.get(),msg_entry.get())
    smtp.quit()

app = tkinter.Tk()
app.title("test")


to_label = tkinter.Label(app,text="To:")
to_entry = tkinter.Entry(app)

from_label = tkinter.Label(app,text="From:")
from_entry = tkinter.Entry(app)

send_button = tkinter.Button(app,text="send",command=connect)

msg_label = tkinter.Label(app,text="Email:")
msg_entry = tkinter.Entry(app,width=50)
#pack(add) the widget to the app.
to_label.pack()
to_entry.pack()

from_label.pack()
from_entry.pack()

msg_label.pack()
msg_entry.pack()

send_button.pack()

#draw the window, have this at the end
app.mainloop()
```

Whenever I hit the send button I get this error

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\Code\Python\Jmail\main.py", line 17, in connect
    smtp.sendmail(from_entry.get(),to_entry.get(),msg_entry.get())
TypeError: sendmail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP("localhost",25)
smtp.sendmail(from_entry.get(),to_entry.get(),msg_entry.get())
```